# Sqlserver query

Tags: sql-server

I need check `Member_Code`,`member_name` and `Designation` in query. If user give only `member_Code` query should bring all record depend on `member_code`, or user give `member_code` and `member_Name` bring the record depend on code and name . i used multiple if and else if in sql server.

I need perfect query for this scenario.

Comment: Please paste your SQL query and your SQL DDL table structure, without that, it will be very hard for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LIKE` in SQLSERVER

try something like this

```
SELECT       *
FROM            table
WHERE        (Member_Code LIKE + '%' + @Member_Code+ '%') OR
                         (member_name LIKE + '%' + @member_name+ '%') OR
                         (Designation LIKE + '%' + @Designation + '%')
```

Comment: sorry I just cut the code my bad :)

Answer (score 0):

Given the lack of information, this is about the best I can do.

try something like

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [Table]
WHERE   (
                Member_Code = @Member_Code 
            AND @member_name IS NULL
        )
OR      (
                Member_Code = @Member_Code 
            AND member_name LIKE '%' + @member_name + '%'
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you may need

```
select 
    columns 
from 
    your_table
where 
    (Member_Code=@Member_Code or @Member_Code is null) and
    (member_name=@member_name  or @member_name  is null) and 
    (Designation=@Designation  or @Designation is null)
```